# Spring integration with JMS glassfish MQ

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, jms

So i have this problem with setting up connection to JMS from Spring project. Problem lies in my Client implementation and it is as follows:

```
public class EndpointHelper implements Runnable{


    @Inject
    public InputDatabaseService inputProxy;

    private Person mickey = new Person("Mickey", "Mouse"); 


    public void run() {

        inputProxy.input(mickey);

    }

}
```

where InputDataService is interface of method input(Person) and input method add person to database.
I got exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpointHelper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public pl.cos.test.camel.service.InputDatabaseService pl.cos.test.ws.endpoint.EndpointHelper.inputProxy; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.MessageFormatException: [C4014]: Serialize message failed. - cause: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext; nested exception is com.sun.messaging.jms.MessageFormatException: [C4014]: Serialize message failed. - cause: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Person.java class:

package pl.famoc.test.camel.service;
import java.io.Serializable;

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setFirst(String first){
        this.firstName = first;
    }
    public void setLast(String last){
        this.lastName = last;
    }
    public String getFirst(){
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLast(){
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

Do anyone have idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: yes, i will edit my post to show how it looks.

Comment: Are you using this class: `XmlWebApplicationContext` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I do not see any direct call to XmlWebApplicationContext  but project i am using is created in maven with archetype org.spring.webservice, so i believe that my main Spring context spring-ws-servlet.xml use it somehow.

Comment: Yes, your application is somehow trying to serialize non-serializable object. That is why this exception is thrown. Can you try to make: `InputDatabaseService` transient? And see what will happen then. What I mean is: `@Inject public transient InputDatabaseService inputProxy;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have figured this out. The problem was not the serialization but the type of `Context` variable that will process the method, by mistake i have made `EndpointHelper` class in the package which is base component of my Spring context : `<context:component-scan base-package="pl.cos.test.ws.endpoint" />` what caused that EndpointHelper was being handeled by `XmlWebApplicationContext` when i wanted `ApplicationContext`.

 Simply putting `EndpointHelper` to another package solved the issue.